# Make Some Text Bold in SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to make only some heading bold of text stored in sqlite database.
Text in dots should be bold.

[image]

Comment: You have to put the data in the db in some format that includes styling.  Like HTML.

Comment: I don't know how to do that....

Comment: You have to change the code that stores and displays the data.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the information out of the database you need to put it in something like a EditText once the data is in that container you can style the view SQLite does not care what the data looks like or what size the text is it just stores TEXT without styling Here is a EditText from a XML file

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etFromDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme" />
```